# .NET Noda Time Converting Local DateTime To UTC for a specific Timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc, nodatime

I am using Noda Time to convert **local datetime** to **UTC**.

This is what I have so far:

```
static string LocalTimeToUTC(string timeZone, string localDateTime)
{
    var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime ldt = pattern.Parse(localDateTime).Value;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.InZoneLeniently(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone]);
    Instant instant = zdt.ToInstant();
    ZonedDateTime utc = instant.InUtc();
    string output = utc.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return output;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (DateTime d in myDates)
    {
        DateTime utcTime = Convert.ToDateTime(LocalTimeToUTC("Europe/Amsterdam", d.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(utcTime);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The problem is with Daylight Savings: When the clock goes 1 hour backwards. There is a missing hour, see the results below.

```
   25/10/2014 19:00:00
   25/10/2014 20:00:00
   25/10/2014 21:00:00
   25/10/2014 22:00:00
   25/10/2014 23:00:00
   26/10/2014 01:00:00
   26/10/2014 02:00:00
```

As you can see, 26/10/2014 00:00:00 is missing due to the clock change.

My question is that is there a way to handle this so that there are no missing hours? Populate the missing hours?

Comment: As an aside, there's no need to go via text parsing here - `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime` is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an hour because there are two UTC instants which both correspond to the same local time, due to the clock going back. The only way of avoiding "missing hours" is to emit *two* entries for the ambiguous local time.

Let's look at a table the other way round, from UTC to local time, with one entry per elapsed hour:

```
UTC                        Local time
2014-10-25 21:00:00Z       2014-10-25 23:00:00 +02
2014-10-25 22:00:00Z       2014-10-26 00:00:00 +02
2014-10-25 23:00:00Z       2014-10-26 01:00:00 +02
2014-10-26 00:00:00Z       2014-10-26 02:00:00 +02
2014-10-26 01:00:00Z       2014-10-26 02:00:00 +01 (clocks back!)
2014-10-26 02:00:00Z       2014-10-26 03:00:00 +01
```

So there are 6 distinct values on the left hand side, but only 5 distinct values on the right hand side.

You can use `DateTimeZone.MapLocal(LocalDateTime)` to get a `ZoneLocalMapping` which will include 0, 1 or 2 values depending on whether the local date/time was skipped (due to a jump forward), unambiguous, or repeated (due to a jump back). That *may* give you what you want, but it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve or what your input data represents.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I do not understand what you mean by that? Could you please put that in the code if possible?

Comment: @Abz: By what, exactly? There's a lot in my post. I'd rather not speculatively write code when you haven't provided a clear idea of what you're trying to achieve... your method can currently only return a single `string`, so it's not clear what you want it to do with ambiguous local values.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have been more specific. Basically, I am retrieving dates (local time) from the database and attempting to convert them to UTC for the respective timezone which in this case is Europe/Amsterdam.

Comment: @Abz: Right, so the problem here is that if you've got an ambiguous local time, e.g. 2014-10-26 02:00:00, there are two UTC values that would map to that same local time. How do you want to handle that?

Comment: I am not sure of how I want to handle it. Any method of handling it will be fine as long as the missing hour can be populated. I am sorry if I am not specific enough because this timezone stuff is new to me.

Comment: @Abz: There isn't a missing hour though. Or if there is, it's because by keeping local date/time values instead of UTC, you've basically lost information. You may have two records with the same local date/time which were *actually* an hour apart, but now you can't tell which is which. There's not a lot that can be done about that, unless there's some other information.

Comment: ahhhh.. I see what you mean. I understand what you did above with the dates UTC -> local time.

Comment: in my database, I do not have two records for 02:00:00

Comment: @Abz: If you don't have two records for 02:00, then it sounds like something may be missing the data.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for your help. Your answers gave me a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if it is possible to create custom DateTimeZone for a non-existing TimeZone?

Comment: @Abz: It would be best to ask that in a new question, with details if possible.